# Codeception code coverage low

Tags: php, integration-testing, code-coverage, codeception

I have constructed a pretty complex code suite for a project with Codeception 
approx 300 tests, with about 3000 assertions. Now I would like to see my codecoverage.

I ran the following line as per the instruction:
`./vendor/bin/codecept run --coverage --coverage-html`

I got a very low score (1%). Which is next to impossible considering that all the assertions that I have created does go to the designated spot in the code when the codecoverage states otherwise.

my codeception.yml file looks like this:

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        \Helper\DbWithMigration:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=travis_test'
            user: 'travis'
            password: ''
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
coverage:
    enabled: true
    include:
        - src/*
        - console/*
```

I have tests for the following: unit, acceptance, console, and api.
They all turn green. I'm unsure where I went wrong

**UPDATE**

Here is my api.suite.yml:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Api
        - REST:
            depends: Silex
        - Silex:
            app: 'tests/_app/bootstrap.php'
        - \Helper\DbWithMigration:
            cleanup: true
        - Asserts
```

and acceptance.suit.yml:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Acceptance
        - REST:
            depends: Silex
        - Silex:
            app: 'tests/_app/bootstrap.php'
        - \Helper\DbWithMigration:
            cleanup: true
        - Asserts
```

and as mentioned i'm running off a VM that has ubuntu 14.04 LTS and PHP 5.6.20 with xdebug.

Comment: Are you running it on HHVM?

Comment: @Naktibalda no PHP 5.6.20, ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What modules are your acceptance and api suites using? You haven't configured remote coverage.

Comment: @Naktibalda added acceptance suite and api suite. If you have a solution for me to try, post a response?

Comment: I don't know what your problem is yet.

Comment: Have you got a 1% test coverage score for lines or classes?